# Prove $\sum_{x\le Q} e(\alpha x)\ll \lVert \alpha\rVert^{-1}$ for $\alpha\not \in\mathbb Z$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I just want to know the proof that $\left\vert\sum_{x\le Q} e(\alpha x)\right\vert\ll \lVert \alpha\rVert^{-1}$ for $\alpha\not \in\mathbb Z$, for any positive integer $Q$. Here $\lVert x\rVert$ means the least distance between $x$ and an integer, and $e(x)=\exp(2\pi i x)$.

Is it also possible to show that
$$\left\vert\sum_{x\le Q} e(2\alpha x)\right\vert\ll \dfrac{1}{\lVert \alpha\rVert}?$$

I doubt perhaps it cannot? Because if we let $m=\exp(2\pi i \alpha)$,
$$\left| \sum_{x\le Q} e(2\alpha x) \right|=\left|\dfrac{m^{2Q}+1}{m+1}\right|\cdot\left|\sum_{x\le Q} e(\alpha x)\right|,$$
but the first term on the right is not bounded by a constant? Is this term bounded by $Q^\epsilon$ (as I've seen from the book involving this that I want to eliminate $\epsilon$ if possible).

---

Edited: Is it okay as follows?
With geometric series calculation we have
$$\left|\sum_{x\le Q}e(\alpha x)\right|=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(2\pi\alpha Q)}{1-\cos(2\pi\alpha)}}.$$

Then we just need to check where $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ for
$$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\alpha^2}{1-\cos(2\pi\alpha)}=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{2\pi^2\cos(2\pi\alpha)}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi^2},$$
by applying L'hospital law? And that thing should be bounded by $\frac{1}{\lVert \alpha \rVert}$? And I mean we just need to show
$$\left|\dfrac{\alpha^2}{1-\cos(2\pi\alpha)}\right|=O(1),$$
for $\alpha\in [-1/2,1/2]-\left\{0\right\}$, which seems to me pretty possible?

--> The graph with the filled hole [Graph plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%28x%5E2%2F%281-cos%282pi*x%29%29%29%2C%20x%3D-0.5%20to%200.5)

Comment: $\lVert\alpha\rVert^{-1}$ is a constant. If you just want to check that $\sum_{0\le x\le Q} e(\alpha x)$ is bounded for all values of $Q>0$ given a fixed $\alpha$, just simplify the geometric series.

Comment: Yes @AdamRubinson

Comment: @ChrisSanders How? I stuck at (for $m=e(\alpha)$)
$$\left|\sum_{x\le Q} e(\alpha x)\right|=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(2\pi\alpha Q)}{1-\cos(2\pi \alpha)}},$$
but don't know how to go further.

Comment: What is the definition of "$\ll$" in this context please?

Comment: Also, do you mean $\sum_{x=1}^Q$ or something else?

Comment: It means there is $k>0$ such that $$\left|\sum_{x\le Q}e(\alpha x)\right|\le \dfrac{k}{\lVert \alpha \rVert}.$$

Comment: @AdamRubinson yes I mean sum over $x=1,2,3,\dots Q$.